# Vibration sensor and its tiny leg

Tags: vibration

Why does a vibration sensor have such a tiny and easy to break second "leg"? Why can't this contact be as strong as the other?

Datasheet is at http://www.beelee-switch.com/uploads/soft/120512/18010P.pdf

[image]

Comment: It's a switch that works with a small metal ball inside making the contact. Have you ever seen a switch that has only one contact ? I think such a switch would be pretty useless. What do you think ?

Comment: A part number might be helpful.

Comment: Part number is in the photo with giant letters ;-)

Comment: I missed the part I said it should only have one contact. The question here aint if it should have one, two or three contacts. I am asking why the second contact has to be so fragile. Maybe now you can post something useful

Comment: @JayCCC You could have put the part number into the question with less typing than your comment about it.

Comment: So what Will Dean?

Comment: @JayCCC - I think you've missed the whole idea of this sort of site - you're asking for free help, and in return you're expected to be as helpful as possible to those whose assistance you're seeking.  You've managed to come across as a complete twat so far.  This is not about some kind of prostration to the high-priests of StackOverflow, it's basic manners.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just that one leg is very thin, the other is very thick, to mechanically couple the switch to the board.  Both legs are as thin as they can be.

Actually, having looked at the datasheet, the thin leg appears to form the spring around the thick leg, so it being thin allows it to perform the function of both the spring and the component lead in one.

Comment: The thicker contact fits perfectly in a breadboard whereas the thin one breaks very easily. There must be a technical reason why this contact is so thin, but you failed to answer it.

Comment: @JayCCC - No, he answered it, you just didn't understand the answer. Please reread the second sentence. The spring needs to be very thin to allow response which is sensitive enough.

Comment: Inside the component I totally agree, however I am talking about the contact not the spring itself

Comment: @JayCCC it's the same wire, both inside and outside the component body.

Comment: There's an interesting question of "why isn't the internal spring (or for that matter, the centre conductor) isolated from the physical mounts of the package?" I presume this is an item-cost or manufacturing constraint, and not a design constraint. Other package styles don't always share this design.